# How to let Chef output logs during execution of package command with action :install?

Tags: chef-infra

I'm using Chef for deployment.
I have a simple recipe like following:

```
package 'my-package' do
    action :install
end
```

When chef-client runs this recipe on Debian, it doesn't tell any progress of apt-get in stdout.
If apt-get failed to install the package, I can't get any information about the failure from the log by chef-client.
I also checked /var/log/apt/term.log but there're no logs for the installation.

Here is the log output by chef-client:

```
[Sat, 09 Mar 2013 22:24:57 +0900] INFO: Processing package[my-package] action install (my-package::default line 19)

================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[my-package]'
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::Exec
----------------------
apt-get -y install my-package=3.0.0 returned 100, expected 0
```

How to let Chef output installation progress of apt-get?
Should I use execute command instead of package command?
Any advices would be very appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: It is not the answer to your question, but to see the exact error that happened, you can ssh to that machine and try to launch `apt-get -y install my-package=3.0.0` by hand. And definitely, don't use `execute` resource for installing packages.

Comment: Thank you, Draco. I'm currently checking the problem by running again manually apt-get as your comment. It's a little pointless way because  Jenkins invokes chef-client and I want to store all informations of the build log as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can supply `-l debug` option to the chief-client.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very Debian/Ubuntu-specific problem. Your `apt-cache` is out of date. You either need to run

```
apt-get update -y
```

On the target machine, or include the [`apt` cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apt) early in your `run_list`.